# Validate only if radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, magento, magento-1.4

I'm trying to modify a PO Box validation script to only validate it if "Ship to this address" is selected. The form apparently uses [really easy form validation](http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation).  The form section is:

```
        <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1" <?php if ($this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_yes"><?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?></label></li>
    <li class="control">
        <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0" <?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no"><?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?></label>
```

So far, the script is

```
Validation.add('validate-pobox', 'One or more items purchased cannot be shipped to a PO Box', function (v){
    var pattern =  /\b([P|p](OST|ost)?\.?\s?[O|o|0](ffice|FFICE)?\.?\s)?([B|b][O|o|0][X|x])\s(\d+)/;
    if( document.getElementById("billing:use_for_shipping_yes").checked) // this isn't working
        if (!pattern.test(v)) return true; else return false;
});
```

I'm not all that familiar with jQuery (I'm slowly learning!), but no matter what I try, the script still validates the address field no matter which button is selected.  I've also tried :

```
if( $("billing:use_for_shipping_yes").checked)
if( $("billing:use_for_shipping_yes").is("checked"))
```

Comment: sorry had to edit my answer, you forgot the color in front of checked and the # for the element ID

Comment: Hmm. I know I had the colon in front of checked at some point. I went back through my revisions to remember what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a colon to checked.  And you forgot the # for the id of the checkbox  http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html

```
if( $("#billing:use_for_shipping_yes").is(":checked"))
```

based on the code I can see it should look like this

```
Validation.add('validate-pobox', 'One or more items purchased cannot be shipped to a PO Box', function (v){
    var pattern =  /\b([P|p](OST|ost)?\.?\s?[O|o|0](ffice|FFICE)?\.?\s)?([B|b][O|o|0][X|x])\s(\d+)/;
    if( $("#billing:use_for_shipping_yes").is(":checked")) {
        if (!pattern.test(v)) {
            return true;
        } else { 
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It still validates it no matter which button is selected.

Comment: I changed your validation some, if this is still not working the problem is not in the jquery selecting the button, so I may need to see more of what you are doing.  Add alert('true'); before return true, and alert('false'); before return false, that way you can see whether or not the validation is even running and what result you are getting.

Comment: Actually, I think I found the issue. It was already defined on the shipping section, so it was overwriting the billing section. By renaming the validation slightly, it should work.  Thanks.